# Zombie.js - Downloading files support

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, zombie.js

I'm trying to handle download prompts in Zombie.js, looking through the [API](http://zombie.labnotes.org/API) I don't see anything indicating how to do so.

Basically what I'm trying to do is navigate through an authentication required website, then click a button on the site (no href) that then automatically engages a download. The downloaded file will then be renamed and sent to a specified folder.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What type of download prompts are they? Are you talking about Windows file dialogs, or are you using a Mac? Or are these some kind of javascript prompt?

Comment: I think this is possible. I can probably help you if let me know exactly what prompts they are.

Comment: What kind of file you want to download?
If it is a text/js file you can just let the browser open it, get the content of the rendered page and save it in a file.
For images/executables/others I don't know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

possibly try:

http://phantomjs.org

you should be able to manipulate the dom...to download.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/Page-Automation

might have to write a separate script to do the file renaming.

Answer (score 5):

Zombie.js doesn't seem to provide a method to directly do what you want, but internally it uses [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) to download files, then emits a `response` event which you can listen for (see [resources.coffee](https://github.com/assaf/zombie/blob/f4e74f94da14b427a4456e9b889182827eab380b/src/zombie/resources.coffee#L95)):

```
var browser = new Zombie();

browser.on('response', function(request, response) {
    browser.response = response;
});

browser.visit('http://test.com/', function() {
    browser.clickLink('Download the file', function() {
        // the 'response' handler should have run by now
        var fileContents = browser.response.body;
    });
});
```

This seems to work pretty well for me.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, and from taking a detailed look at the API of Zombie.js, I'd say *no, this is not possible*.

I know it's not the answer you hoped for, but truth is not always nice.